# How to convert DateTime to Integer and check the difference?

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to compare the difference between two times in the day. I'm getting time in UTC format. Do I have to convert DateTime to integer in order to get the difference and if yes how?

This is my code

```
Dim ct As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
        Dim int_ct As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(ct)
        MsgBox(ct + " | " + int_ct)
        If (System.IO.File.Exists(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath.ToString + "\tempfile.data")) Then
            Dim time As DateTime = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath.ToString + "\tempfile.data")
            Dim int_time As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(time)
            If ((int_ct - unlockedtime) < int_time) Then 'unlockedtime is Int variable
                Return False
            Else
                Return True
            End If
        End If
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do any timezone conversion, just make sure that both date/time values are in the same timezone when you capture them (though I suppose it might be wise use to `UtcNow` in case the system timezone changes in-between your two measurements.

You don't need to convert values to `Int32` to get the difference, just use the `DateTime.Subtract` method:

```
Dim old As DateTime = GetOldDateTime()
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.UtcNow
Dim diff As TimeSpan = now.Subtract( old )

If diff.TotalSeconds > someSecondsValue Then
    DoSomething()
End If
```

Comment: I have the "someSecondsValue" as an integer variable. Is there a way to convert that integer value to TimeSpan somehow to compare it, cause I'm getting an error that I can't compare those two values.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Datetime.Compare(dt1,dt2)? Depending on how much detail you need this might work for you.

Here is more information on the function:
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.compare.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1

Answer (score 1):

As Dai said you may want to compare difference, but if you just want the date difference you can use the following:

```
DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, Date1, date2)
```

This returns the difference as an integer, you can set whatever date interval you require as the firt parameter.